# Does anyone know the font of the Zitana logo?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image: Zitana logo]

What the font has no answer at all. We created the logo more than 5 years ago.

Comment: Hi Sven, welcome to the site. We have some [font identification question requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366/8708), I've made some edits to your question so that it meets them. Next time, please be sure to check that first!

Answer (score 5):

This is [Arkitech Light](http://www.dafont.com/arkitech.font?text=zitana) by Neogrey Creative.

[image: Arkitech Light font sample]

I found this using [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/), a font search engine similar to WhatTheFont but it searches free fonts. Any time WhatTheFont can't identify a sample, it's a good indication that it's a free font.